# NSString from [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsdata

There is probably a really simple answer for this, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

I am getting the contents of a web URL using (See Below)

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webURL];
```

What I want to do is display this NSData in a readable form, not the hexadecimal representation.

Comment: what type of resource is located at `webURL` ?

Comment: Its just a web page with text on it, I was hoping to scrape the text off it but maybe I am going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Using NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; seems to have worked, it does give me the html source but I can pick through that to get the data I need.

Comment: Do any of the current answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 7):

This is also another way, bypassing the use of NSData altogether:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:webURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is just for display/logging, and you don't really need the string in your program, you can also set a breakpoint (click on the line numbers in the line you want to log).

Then right click the breakpoint you just created --> *Edit breakpoint* --> *Click to add an action*. Set the dropdown to *debugger command*, and in the *Action* text field, enter `x/10s (char*)[data bytes]`. This will write 10 "segments" of your data to the log. Check the *Automatically continue...* checkbox so the breakpoint doesn't halt the program.

[image: NSData logging breakpoint in Xcode4]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", response);
```